# How to conditionally select elements in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I couldn't find any examples that match my use case. Still working through my way in python lists and dictionaries.

Problem:

```
all_cars = {'total_count': 3,'cars': [{'name': 'audi','model': 'S7'}, {'name': 'honda', 'model': 'accord'},{'name': 'jeep', 'model': 'wrangler'} ]} 

owners = {'users':[{'owner': 'Nick', 'car': 'audi'},{'owner': 'Jim', 'car': 'ford'},{'owner': 'Mike', 'car': 'mercedes'} ]} 


def duplicate(): 
   for c in all_cars['cars']: 
     if c['name'] == [c['users']for c in owners['users']]: 
        pass 
     else: 
        res = print(c['name']) 
   return res

output = ['honda', 'jeep', audi']
```

and

```
def duplicate(): 
   for c in all_cars['cars']: 
     if c['name'] == 'audi': 
        pass 
     else: 
        res = print(c['name']) 
   return res 

output - ['honda', 'jeep']
```

I am trying to find matching values in both dictionaries, using list comprehension, then return non-matching values only.

> Solution: Using 'in' rather than '==' operator, I was able to compare values between both lists and skip duplicates.

```
def duplicate(): 
   for c in all_cars['cars']: 
     if c['name'] in [c['users']for c in owners['users']]: 
        pass 
     else: 
        res = print(c['name']) 
   return res
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your 'list comprehensions' are not valid Python syntax. Please update the actual format of the data you're working with.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please? It is worded a bit confusingly.

Comment: @Nick I want to return a list of non-duplicate values.

Comment: @SunnyPatel I just updated the format and the list comprehension.

Comment: Is each value in `all_cars['cars']` and `owners['users']` unique? Do you have the luxury to modify this data type? I would **highly** suggest converting your array of `all_cars['cars']` and your `owners['users']` into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) types. You will get SUPER fast performance to do any set operations.

Comment: @SunnyPatel values in are not unique. And no, I cannot modify the data. I'll look into the sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on your feedback on the solution above, here is how I would tackle your problem.  Drop your common items into lists and then use "set" to print out the diff.

```
    all_cars = {'total_count': 3,'cars': [{'name': 'audi','model': 'S7'}, 
        {'name': 'honda', 'model': 'accord'},{'name': 'jeep', 'model': 'wrangler'} ]}

    owners = {'users':[{'owner': 'Nick', 'car': 'audi'},{'owner': 'Jim', 
        'car': 'ford'},{'owner': 'Mike', 'car': 'mercedes'} ]}

    allCarList = []
    ownerCarList = []
    for auto in all_cars['cars']:
        thisCar = auto['name']
        if thisCar not in allCarList:
            allCarList.append(thisCar)

    for o in owners['users']:
        thisCar = o['car']
        if thisCar not in ownerCarList:
            ownerCarList.append(thisCar)

    diff = list(set(allCarList) - set(ownerCarList))
    print(diff)
```

I put this in and ran it and came up with this output:

```
    ['jeep', 'honda']
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title, you can conditionally add elements during a list comprehension using the syntax `[x for y in z if y == a]`, where `y == a` is any condition you need - if the condition evaluates to `True`, then the element `y` will be added to the list, otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 1):

I would just keep a dictionary of all of the owner data together:

```
    ownerData = { "Shaft" : {
              "carMake" : "Audi",
              "carModel" : "A8",
              "year" : "2015" },
         "JamesBond" : {
              "carMake" : "Aston",
              "carModel" : "DB8",
              "year" : "2012" },
         "JeffBezos" : {
              "carMake" : "Honda",
              "carModel" : "Accord"
              "year" : "1989"}
         }
```

Now you can loop through and query it something like this:

```
    for o in ownerData:
         if "Audi" in o["carMake"]:
              print("Owner %s drives a %s %s %s" % (o, o["year"], o["carMake"], o["carModel"]))
```

Should output:

```
    "Owner Shaft drives a 2015 Audi A8"
```

This way you can expand your data set for owners without creating multiple lists.

Comment: So these are two separate data pulled from separate endpoints.